# New beta version of android application is not distributed

Tags: android, google-play

I had published beta version of my app on the market. Then I published new beta version but devices does not detect that new beta version is available. It has been more than 18 hours since I release new beta version.

If I uninstall app and then re-install... still old version of beta is getting installed even though I have deactivated that version on Google Play.

I don't see any errors or warnings on Google Play. Did any one encounter similar issues ?

Comment: Are you able to see the new beta version on Google Play using a desktop/laptop?

Comment: Be a little more patient before assuming there is a problem. 18 hours is not that long - it can take a day or more for published updates to become effective.

Comment: Yes..I can see the beta version with status in beta in Google Play. I was able to distribute first version but devices are not detecting new version.

Comment: It took over 24 hours for apk to become available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to wait a little longer. It took over 24 hours for the published APK to become available.